# Spy on does not return true , although the code triggers the event

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I have this Jasmine 2 test I am trying to understand why it does not pass.

```
describe('Some functionality', () => {

let fixture;
let nativeElement;
let componentInstance;

beforeEachProviders(() => [
    CenterOnMeButton,
    EventAggregatorService,
    GeoLocationService,
    provide(GoogleMapsAPIWrapper, {useClass: StabGoogleMapsApiWrapper}),
    provide(MapController, {useClass: StabMapControllerService}),
    provide(MapEventsService, {useClass: StabMapEventsService})
]);

beforeEach(injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder, GoogleMapsAPIWrapper, GeoLocationService, MapController
    ], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder ) => {

    return tcb
        .createAsync(CenterOnMeButton).then((componentFixture: ComponentFixture<CenterOnMeButton>) => {

            ({nativeElement, componentInstance} = componentFixture);
            fixture = componentFixture;
            componentFixture.detectChanges();
        });
}));

it('should emit an event when center button is clicked',
    injectAsync([EventAggregatorService], (eventAggregator: EventAggregatorService) => {
    spyOn(eventAggregator, 'trigger');
    spyOn(componentInstance, 'toogleEnableGeolocation');
    nativeElement.querySelector('.toggle.fa.fa-crosshairs').click();
    expect(eventAggregator.trigger).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(componentInstance.toogleEnableGeolocation).toHaveBeenCalled();

}));

});
```

Center On Me Button
   × should emit enableGeolocation event when center button is clicked, but it fails:
 Expected spy trigger to have been called.

The method I am spying on:

```
trigger(event: BaseEvent): EventAggregatorService {
    const eventType = event.constructor.name;
    const subject: Subject<BaseEvent> = this._subjects[eventType];
    if (subject) {
        subject.next(event);
    }
    return this;
}
```

I would expect(eventAggregator.trigger).toHaveBeenCalled() to be true. It is when I debug the app, but the test fails. Any hint ?

Comment: You don't need to check that the method is called. You may need to check that `componentFixture.detectChanges()` is called. Anyway you are trying to test things in a strange way. Why do you spy on the method you want to test?

Comment: I know I do not need to check, since it is not the class I am testing, but it frustrates me , why it does not work, spying on that method when I used spyOn(eventAggregator, 'trigger') ?

Comment: I think the object `eventAggregator` that you are referring to is not the same object that the function is calling and therefore the spyon doesn't work